# How to provide data in service constructor?

Tags: angular

There is a service Angular:

```
@Injectable()
export class SortService {
  constructor(private sortField = "date", private sortDirection = true) {}
}
```

I have registered this service in module providers section.

How to pass default values to constructor?

I get this message now:

> ncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SortService: (?, ?).

Comment: This is an injectable service which is managed by Angular. You would never ‘new’ this class yourself as it is managed through Angular Dependency injection. If you want a ‘normal’ class for which you can create your own instances, just remove the injectable decorator. This often doesn’t make sense though as for services you would usually want singletons.

Comment: So, after remove injectable decorator how to use it? Like new A() ? in component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose either of these **3 methods:**

**1.) Set default values by private variable instance**

```
@Injectable()
export class SortService {

  // default values and private fields only accessible in this service
  private sortField = "date";
  private sortDirection = true;

  constructor() {}

  // If later you want to update the sort config 
  setSortConfig(field: string, direction: boolean): void {
     this.sortField = field;
     this.sortDirection = direction;
  }

}
```

**2.) Set default values inside the Module's providers**

*Module*

```
@NgModule({
   ...,
   providers: [
     { 
        provide: 'sortConfig',     // you can also integrate InjectionToken on this
        useValue: { sortField: 'date', sortDirection: true } 
     }
   ]
})
```

**- You can access it via `Component` or `Service`**

*Component*

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class TestComponent {

   constructor(@Inject('sortConfig') private sortConfig: any) {}

}
```

*Service*

```
@Injectable()
export class SortService {

   constructor(@Inject('sortConfig') private sortConfig: any) {}

}
```

**3.) Set default values via Service Factory `(Your case)`**

Have created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-factory-demo?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for this example:

*Module*

```
@NgModule({
   ...,
   providers: [
      // Upon loading this particular service inside the module, 
      // any component under this module that utilizes SortService 
      // will run as expected with the default values supplied below
      { 
         provide: SortService, 
         useFactory: () => new SortService('date', true)
      }

   ]
})
```

*Service*

```
@Injectable()
export class SortService {

  constructor(
     private sortField,
     private sortDirection
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: Why this `@Inject('sortConfig') private sortConfig: any` inside component not inside service constructor?

Comment: I still dont get why we inject it inside component instead service, only service needs it

Comment: Hi Alice, you can inject in Component or Service. You can choose either of the two on where do you want to utilize the data :) Have updated the example above on Method #2

Answer (score 0):

You have wrote the injectable service. That error was causing due to `@Injectable()`.

- Remove `@Injectable()`
- Use `new` keyword while initializing the service class.

app.component.ts

```
 export class AppComponent {
  private myServices: SortService;
  constructor() {
    this.myServices = new SortService("date", false);
  }
 }
```

Checkout the Angular Dependency Injection: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class dataBaseService{

serviceData: string = "default value unset";

getData():string{
    return this.serviceData;
}

setData(value:string){
  this.serviceData = value;
}
}
```